# What value does a database use to represent NULL on disk?

Tags: database, internals

When a database system writes a record to a page on disk, and one of the fields in that record is null, what value is used to represent that 'null' such that when the record is read back in, it knows that the field is 'null.'

Perhaps it is dependent on the data-type of that field?

Comment: I think this varies between databases.  SQLMenace's answer probably only applies to MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Peter - I agree.  If you happen to find other databases methods of doing these, I would definitely be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Based on no proof whatsoever,  I would guess that if anyone does it differently, it is oracle, as they have the problem/feature of not distinguishing between null and the empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses a NULL bitmap, you can use [DBCC PAGE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/83065) to take a closer look

Check out this link for more detail [Poking about with DBCC PAGE](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/08/09/692806.aspx)

Comment: I was almost certain it was metadata related.  Thanks for the links.